# Running an .exe file through a batch file and passing parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I have an .exe file that takes two parameters when i run it from the command line, as such:

```
test_app.exe -vid.avi -data.txt
```

How would i be able to `START` the `.exe` file through a batch script and pass it those parameters?

If i have multiple `.avi` and `.txt` files that i need to pass to the `.exe` file through `START`, how would i be able to have a variable that goes through all of those files two at a time? (pairing every `.avi` with it's correspondant `.txt`).

Let's assume that every pair of `.avi` and `.txt` share the same name but obviously have different extensions.

I need to write something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
START test_app.exe -vid.avi -data.txt
pause
```

But the parameters should be variables that increment every time a pair of parameters are proccessed through the `.exe` so it would loop on all of the files in the CWD.

Trying to do this but seems like START does not work that way?

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.avi) do (
START Tester.exe -%%a -%%~na.txt
)
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it works with AVI as the main extension, you may change this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.avi) do (
    set "line="
    for %%j in ("%%~ni.*") do set line=!line! -"%%~j"
    start "" test_app.exe !line!
)
```

Comment: Is the .txt file also added into !line!? It's a bit confusing for me since i barely have any experience with this, sorry.

Comment: All files with the same name are on the line, eg. vid.avi, vid.txt, vid.dta. What files do you need at one line?

Comment: in every line i need to start the exe and give it two parameters... the avi and txt files.

Comment: And where do the parameters come from?

Comment: from the current directory. It has a bunch of avi's and txt's. every pair of avi+txt share the same name

Comment: @MaxPower yes, this does my code: search for an AVI and collect all files with the same name & put it at the line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with your avi files.  It will just echo the bunch of commands and you can see what it does.  The - signs seem a bit odd but I included them with the names.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.avi) do (
echo exe.file "-%%a" "-%%~na.txt"
)
pause
```

Comment: I need to actually start the exe file with those parameters, i don't understand how echo helps here... sorry if i totally missed the point.

Comment: You haven't supplied an authentic command line - but I supplied the code to launch the exe with the two files.  All you need to do is replace the exe filename, and remove the echo, assuming that `"-filename.avi" "-filename.txt"` is what you need to feed the exe file with.  The echo was to show you what the code was doing.

Comment: Your command line looks wrong.  The switches aren't normal. MOITester.exe doesn't get a hit in google so I can't help you with what the syntax is.

Comment: MOITester is just a random name. I don't understand what you mean by the switches aren't normal. all i'm trying to do is call tester.exe and pass it two arguments at a time. One being .avi and the other being .txt

Comment: `test_app.exe -vid.avi -data.txt`  Does that work for you?  It is the information you provided, and if it doesn't work then the code I provided isn't going to work either.  Show us what works for you with your executable.

Comment: this "test_app.exe -vid.avi -data.txt" works through the command line. But through a batch file i need to use START i think... and that is what does not work. I can only do it one by one using hte command line. What i am trying to do is automate the proccess to have it run on all files in the current directory.